# How to constantly get Information from the Backend into the dom in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dom

I got a question concerning the relationship of the DOM and my Backend. I have a website running with node.js and express and now I want to implement a "live counter" feature.

The counter should actualize every 10 seconds or so and show the user the current "score". The problem is that this score is saved in my Mongo-Database and but I want to show the new information to the user (without loading a completely new page, this would be annoying).

It is no problem for me to run a script that actulizes every seconds or so, but I either had to:

1) Let a script run on the client side and retrieve information from my DB like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    //get Information from Server (X)
    //manipulate div in the DOM 

    }, 1000
);
```

Or 2) Let a script run on the server side and somehow manipulate the DOM from there

```
setInterval(function(){
     //get value from DB
     //somehow access DOM and change the value there (X)

    }, 1000
);
```

(The "(X)" marks the tricky part for me)

I also know that it is not really possible to manipulate the DOM from node and not a good idea to access my DB from the clientside. But I am out of ideas here. Can some of you explain to me how this problem could be solved?

Thanks a lot,
Paul

Comment: Use socket https://socket.io/.

Comment: Socket.io is a great use case for this.  Alternately, if you want to use jquery's ajax functions, you can do that, and update the HTML elements accordingly given the response.

Comment: I agree with socket.io as a good choice, but I would also highly recommend looking into firebase, it's like mongo+socket.io with an api

Answer (score -1):

You can use socket.io for this type of problem  where you can emit the data from your server on specific time interval or on any specific event. And then subscribe that event to get that data in realtime.